# Toggle Mute/Unmute video's Audio progressively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With this code I want to toggle mute/unmute a playing video's Audio with a fadeIn fadeOut effect:

```
const btn = document.getElementById('mute'),
      video = document.querySelector('#video_mainhub');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (btn.value === 'unmuted') {
    btn.value = 'muted';
    btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-volume-mute"></i>';
    $('#video_mainhub').animate({volume: 0}, 1000);
    video.muted = true;
  } else {
    btn.value = 'unmuted';
    btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-volume-up"></i>';
    $('#video_mainhub').animate({volume: 1}, 1000);
    video.muted = false;
  }
});

<a id="mute" value="muted"><i class="fas fa-volume-mute"></i></a>
```

However, it is not working, anything I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things we can identify and improve.

- Anchor elements do not have a `value` attribute so `btn.value = 'muted'` amounts to nothing
- Make use of jQuery to simplify matters at hand.
- We can toggle the icon class rather than replace the `innerHTML` which can be expensive in the grand scheme of things.
- I wouldn't rely on `.animate()` to modify the volume. But that opens another avenue and for demonstration purposes we'll stick to what you know.

Try this.

```js
const $btn = $('#mute'),
      $video = $('#video_mainhub')

let isAnimating = false

$btn.on('click', () => {
  if (isAnimating) return

  let video = $video[0]
  let volumeTo;

  if (video.muted) {
    video.muted = false
    video.volume = 0
  }
  if (video.volume > 0) volumeTo = 0
  else if (video.volume < 1) volumeTo = 1

  // Toggle icon
  $btn.find('.fas')
    .removeClass(volumeTo === 1 ? 'fa-volume-mute' : 'fa-volume-up')
    .addClass(volumeTo !== 1 ? 'fa-volume-mute' : 'fa-volume-up')
  
  // Toggle volume
  isAnimating = true
  $video.stop(true, true).animate(
    {volume: volumeTo},
    1000,
    () => isAnimating = false
  )
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video id="video_mainhub" playsinline autoplay muted controls width="400" src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4"></video>

<a id="mute"><i class="fas fa-volume-mute"></i></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - with your code I was able to reproduce the fadeIn of the sound, however, it doesn't do the fadeIn on the first time the button is clicked (my video starts muted). Any tips? Thanks

Comment: I've modified the code to consider mute state (since volume change bears no impact on mute). To clarify, we unmute and set `volume = 0` if muted. Subsequently audio should fade in/out. I have added the `isAnimating` flag for a smoother toggle.